# The value of \hsize in ams classes is 0pt in the preamble

Tags: tex-core, amsart

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\showthe\hsize
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

returns `0pt` but

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\showthe\hsize
...
\end{document}
```

returns `360pt`. Is the first case a bug? I can imagine if some packages do calculation like:

```
\divide\baselineskip by \hsize
```

then, one would get `Arithmetic overflow error`.

Comment: i hope that there's no reason to divide `\baselineskip` (a vertical measure) by `\hsize` (a horizontal measure).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: There is. This is the kind of calculation you will do when you want to implement paragraph footnotes. See `fnpara` package for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really a bug and in many ways it's more consistent than the standard classes which do set it. `\hsize` is not a document parameter like `\textwidth`; it just has local values in different contexts to control the line breaking widths for TeX's linebreaker. LaTeX intentionally sets things up such that starting a paragraph that would invoke the linebreaker in the preamble invokes the missing `\begin{document}` error, so not setting `\hsize` to a usable value is consistent with that.

Note that whatever the class, the latex format ignores the value of `\hsize` in the preamble and sets a suitable value based on `\textwidth` and the number of columns, while processing `\begin{document}` so `amsart` does not do anything special to set up `\hsize` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Not only that `\hsize` returns `0pt` but also `\columnwidth` returns `0pt` too in the preamble.